# for loop including pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I tried to output a string "Hello" using pointer. Here is the code

```
char s[] = "Hello";  
char * p;
for( p = s; p[0]; ++ p )     
    cout << * p;
return 0;
```

I don't understand why `p[0]` in the for loop can work.

Answer (score 10):

`p[0]` is exactly equivalent to `*p` in this case. It will evaluate to `'\0'` at the end of your array, which means a numerical value of 0, which then gets converted to a value of false and stops the loop.

Comment: "Typically"? Is it not guaranteed?

Comment: Yea, that's a really convoluted way to spell `*p` which I'd say is semantically incorrect, because p is in fact not an array. I'd imagine compilers warn about it on some pedantic settings.

Comment: @luk32 `p[0]` is literally defined to be `*(p+0)`. There's nothing wrong with it. In fact we use array subscripting into a pointer all the time! (Almost any time you subscript into a C string, comes to mind...) I wouldn't expect any warning; that'd be really noisy. Also the standard mentions pointers as well as arrays in [the relevant rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#1). Of course, it was an odd choice here. Wonder why the OP "wrote" it when they didn't know what it does ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It very well might be. That doesn't change the fact, that the pointer was never a pointer to an array, which makes applying array notation dubious.

Comment: @luk32: It points to the elements of `s`. There is nothing dubious about it! Would you make the same claim about `const char* str = "hello world"; std::cerr << str[5] << '\n';`? Because that is exactly the same thing :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Umm... If I'm reading the Standard right, `'\0'` is actually an _octal_ number 0; [`\0` is _not_ on the list of predefined escape sequences](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#nt:character-literal), so it fits the `\ooo` pattern.

Comment: why only in this case? `p[0]` is always equivalent to `*p` for pointers. or did you mean in case `p` is not a pointer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ok. You're absolutely right. I've missed that fact. `p` is simply an open ended array of elements of `s` which is shifted vs original one, and we just happen to use it's "0th" element. Even semantics fit. I stand corrected. For some reason I thought it's the same as doing `T* t = new T; t[0];` which I'd argue is not semantically correct, but that's not it.

Comment: @user463035818 In this case, where `p` is a pointer. It might not mean the same for user-defined types.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Note that `0` is also an octal constant. Personally I'd love to have a drink and maybe more with the person who first came up with `'\0'`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, the digit in `'\0'`is octal. But, octal or not, zero is zero.